# x and y axis not displaying values ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to plot the x an y axis in ggplot using geom_point() or geom_bar() I only get one value displayed on each axis. I am using the following data set.

```
startup_data <- read.csv('crunchbase_monthly_export.csv', header = T, 
stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

ggplot(startup_data, aes(factor(funding_rounds))) + geom_bar()

ggplot(ft2) +
geom_point(mapping = aes("funding_rounds", "funding_total_usd"))
```

Thanks in advance
Lee

Comment: `aes` expects unquoted column names, not strings. Try `aes(funding_rounds, funding_total_usd)`, assuming those are columns in `ft2`/

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post some sample data to make  your question reproducible. [See lots of help for making reproducible examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061).

Comment: Thank you for the assistance and examples

Comment: I worked out that some of the values in the columns were being stored as characters. Converting to a tibble helped me get the result I was after.